# Displaying views onto specific Collection View Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I am trying to display pre-coded Page/View cells onto their respective cells in my collection view controller.

I've created all the pages without the use of storyboards.

I've created 3 cells but now I am trying to figure out how to put each view into their respective view. I created an array of my 3 classes(pages) but can't figure out how to connect them to separate cells in "cellForItemAt" I tried playing with indexPaths and collectionview.cellForItem(at: ___) but I haven't been able to achieve what I want.

How can I go about connecting the pages in my array to the right cells?

Thanks

```
let pages = [AboutPageCell, MainPageCell, InfoPageCell]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where have you created the Views of your cell? in a .xib or the storyboard?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention, i created them all programmatically without storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly add this to the ViewController

```
let cellIdentifier = ["AboutPageCell", "MainPageCell", "InfoPageCell"]
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` register your cells like

```
tableView.register(AboutPageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier[0])
tableView.register(MainPageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier[1])
tableView.register(InfoPageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier[2])
```

Your `cellForItemAt` will be

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cellToReturn = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier[indexPath.row])

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let aboutPageCell = cellToReturn as! AboutPageCell

            // Configure you propertie here

            cellToReturn = aboutPageCell
        case 1:
            let mainPageCell = cellToReturn as! MainPageCell

            // Configure you propertie here

            cellToReturn = mainPageCell
        case 2:
            let infoCell = cellToReturn as! InfoPageCell

            // Configure you propertie here

            cellToReturn = infoCell
        default:
            break
        }

        return cellToReturn
    }
```